# Adding Hours to DateTimePicker in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How to add 3 hours in DateTimePicker in VS?

```
    Dim dateAdd as Date = DateTimePicker1

    dateAdd.AddHours(3)

    MsgBox(dateAdd.Value.ToString)
```

Why does it doesn't add on my system?

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime.AddHours()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx) returns a new DateTime:

```
Dim dateAdd as Date = DateTimePicker1

Dim newDate as Date = dateAdd.AddHours(3)

MsgBox(newDate.Value.ToString)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I used this ...  MsgBox(dtp_ArrivalDate.Value.AddHours(3))